# Minimalistic key from functional dependancy?

Tags: database, functional-programming, normalization

I'm just trying to learn about functional dependancies and I have become stuck on a question. I have to find the minimalistic key for R.

Relation R(S, T, U, V ,W ,X ,Y Z)

FD(S->TUV, TV->W, WXY->Z, X->YZ)

How would I go about doing this?